ID: Ant or ant-like insect in North Central FL (velvet ant?)
I heard my cats messing with something in my apartment, and when I went to check on them, I found them playing with this insect:

It's roughly a centimeter long. I am located in North Central Florida. I'm leaning toward a female velvet ant. When I showed up, a cat ran away from it and was licking his paw pretty intently, so I want to be sure of what it is in case it stung or bit him (he seems completely fine now, so it might just have been a sensory response from touching it).

You nailed it; that's a female velvet ant, a member of the Mutillidae wasp family.
Only the (flightless) females sting, and their sting is reportedly very painful. However, they're not aggressive, and sting only defensively.

Velvet ants are not ants at all; they are wasps in the family Mutillidae. Although more common in the southwestern U.S., they can be found throughout the Southeast.

From the second link:

They are known for their extremely painful stings, (the sting of the species Dasymutilla klugii rated a 3 on the Schmidt pain index and lasts up to 30 minutes[1]), and has resulted in the common name "cow killer" or "cow ant" being applied to the species Dasymutilla occidentalis.[2] However, mutillids are not aggressive and sting only in defense.

